# Reinstall Outlook 2003 and use BCM2007, or any way to use BCM2003 on an exchange server?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office-2007

I currently have Office 2007 with BCM installed on my new laptop, and it's getting annoying that Outlook 2007 seems to crash on a regular basis, which seems to be because I work from home and the data connection is unstable to the server.

My two fold question is :
a) Is there any way to use BCM2007 with an old version of Office, and 
b) Is there any way to use BCM2003 when your mail connection is through an Exchange server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that has the same problem, I downgraded to MSO2003 (via complete uninstalls), after finding a patch on Microsoft's website that allows BCM2003 to work within an Exchange environment.